# awk variables print as options in bash

Tags: bash

I'm trying to make a script which reads your firefox profile.ini file, gives you options for which profile you want to unlock and execute a simple rm on the .lock file of the given profile (useful when you run multiple firefox sessions between workstations in different buildings and you did not logout correctly

I have the following file profile.ini for example

```
[General]
StartWithLastProfile=0

[Profile0]
Name=default
IsRelative=1
Path=rkfddmkn.default
Default=1

[Profile1]
Name=NX
IsRelative=1
Path=sf18055j.NX

[Profile14]
Name=gutter
IsRelative=1
Path=sf18055judsfsdfdfds.gutter

[Profile556]
Name=Jerusalem
IsRelative=1
Path=234920fgffdg38.Jerusalem
```

And this is the first part

```
ini=$HOME/.mozilla/firefox/profiles.ini
The script checks if profiles.ini exists otherwise exit 
    if [ -f $ini ]
            then
The script reads the profiles.ini file and return multiple profiles as options followed by the name of the profiles

profiles=`cat $ini | grep "Profile[0-9*]"`
echo $profiles | awk -v RS=" " '{print}'
names=`cat $ini | grep Name | sed s/Name=/\/`
echo $names | awk -v RS=" " '{print}'
echo $options = $profiles . ' ' . $names; | awk -v RS=" " '{print}'
```

I'm not sure if I'm going down the right path.
How can I prompt the user to select an option by pairing the awk strings ?

Comment: You want the user to select a profile *name*, and then delete the *path*? I'd like to be sure it's clear what you're trying to accomplish here, because it's a lot easier to start the code from scratch.

Comment: You don't need to pipe grep to sed, you can do that with sed itself: `sed '/Name=/s/Name=//' "$ini"`

Comment: I'd argue that a better approach wouldn't use *any* pipes at all. Spinning up a bunch of external processes means one needs to recombine their output; do all the logic in native bash, and not only is all the startup overhead avoided, but one doesn't need to piece things back together (and worry about their output being misaligned due to a logic bug) in the first place.

Comment: @dquake: Note also that parsing INI-files with bash/awk is possible, but not fun. Use some ini-file parser, for instance from [Ruby](https://rubygems.org/gems/inifile/versions/3.0.0), [Python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html) or [Perl](https://metacpan.org/pod/Config::IniFiles).

Answer (score 2):

A native-bash parser that breaks the relevant part of your input file into three associative arrays might look something like the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -x; PS4=':$LINENO+'

section_re='^\[Profile(.*)\][[:space:]]*$'
kv_re='^([[:alnum:]]+)=(.*)'

declare -A profilesByName=( )
declare -A profileNames=( )
declare -A profilePaths=( )

current_section=
while IFS= read -r line; do : line="$line"
  [[ $line =~ $section_re ]] && { current_section=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}; continue; }
  [[ $line =~ $kv_re ]] || continue
  [[ $current_section ]] || continue ## ignore k/v pairs if not in a section
  key=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}; value=${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
  case $key in
    Name) profileNames[$current_section]=$value
          profilesByName[$value]=$current_section ;;
    Path) profilePaths[$current_section]=$value ;;
  esac
done
```

Then, if you want to delete the lockfile associated with a given profile name, it becomes as simple as:

```
deleteLockForName() {
  local desiredName=$1
  local selectedProfile selectedPath
  selectedProfile=${profilesByName[$desiredName]}
  [[ $selectedProfile ]] || { echo "ERROR: No profile with name $desiredName found" >&2; return 1; }
  selectedPath=${profilePaths[$selectedProfile]}
  echo "Deleting $selectedPath.lck" >&2
  rm -f -- "$selectedPath.lck"
}
```

...as used in:

```
deleteLockForName Jerusalem
```

You can see it running at https://ideone.com/d0QFYa -- in the above example invocation, emitting `Deleting 234920fgffdg38.Jerusalem.lck`.

Comment: Dang! you got me by 4 minutes -- but I had whittled it down to a `select` loop after joining `"${profiles[i]} ${names[i]}"`.

Comment: Sounds like an answer worth adding. :)

Comment: Yes indeed. I'll collect the pieces, unset the variables in my shell, and see what I can cobble together.

Answer (score 1):

[@CharlesDuffy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14122/charles-duffy) is always a tough act to follow (try it...), but I took a somewhat different approach to solving your problem.

First, you don't need to deal with `$HOME/.mozilla/firefox/profiles.ini` at all. All you need to deal with is those profiles that have an existing `lock` symlink within their profile directory. So create an array just holding the names of the directories with with a `lock` symlink present to display to the user to remove. You can do that with `find` and `sed` in a simple *command-substitution*, e.g.

```
#!/bin/bash

moz="$HOME/.mozilla/firefox"

## locate all lockfile links that exist below "$moz"
readarray -t lockfiles < <(find "$moz" -type l -name lock -printf '%P\n')
```

Next, the `select` loop in bash will create a numbered menu with entries being the profile directories in your `lockfiles` array. The user can select the number corresponding to the profile directory name to remove (`unlink`) the `lock` symlink in that directory. For example:

```
## set prompt for select menu
PS3="Selection: "

## prompt
printf "\nThe following lockfiles found, select to remove, Quit to end:\n\n"

## create menu listing existing lockfile links
select lockname in "${lockfiles[@]%/*}" "Quit"; do 
    [ "$lockname" = "Quit" ] && break
    if [ -h "$moz/$lockname/lock" ]; then
        printf "\ndeleting lock %s\n" "$moz/$lockname/lock"
        ## uncomment to actually remove link
        # unlink "$moz/$lockname/lock"
        break
    else
        printf "\nerror: invalid selection.\n" >&2
    fi
done
```

(**note:** setting `PS3` controls the prompt displayed by the `select` loop, instead of the generic `#?`. Also note the `/lock` was trimmed from the contents of the array to display only the profile directory name in the `select` loop declaration with `"${lockfiles[@]%/*}"`)

Putting it altogether, you would have:

```
#!/bin/bash

moz="$HOME/.mozilla/firefox"

## locate all lockfile links that exist below "$moz"
readarray -t lockfiles < <(find "$moz" -type l -name lock -printf '%P\n')

## set prompt for select menu
PS3="Selection: "

## prompt
printf "\nThe following lockfiles found, select to remove, Quit to end:\n\n"

## create menu listing existing lockfile links
select lockname in "${lockfiles[@]%/*}" "Quit"; do 
    [ "$lockname" = "Quit" ] && break
    if [ -h "$moz/$lockname/lock" ]; then
        printf "\ndeleting lock %s\n" "$moz/$lockname/lock"
        ## uncomment to actually remove link
        # unlink "$moz/$lockname/lock"
        break
    else
        printf "\nerror: invalid selection.\n" >&2
    fi
done
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ bash ff_rm_lock.sh

The following lockfiles found, select to remove, Quit to end:

1) 3cblo6ag.dcr_new
2) Quit
Selection: 1

deleting lock /home/david/.mozilla/firefox/3cblo6ag.dcr_new/lock
```

or using `"Quit"` leaving all `lock` symlinks in place:

```
$ bash ff_rm_lock.sh

The following lockfiles found, select to remove, Quit to end:

1) 3cblo6ag.dcr_new
2) Quit
Selection: 2
```

(**note:** you must uncomment the line `unlink "$moz/$lockname/lock"` to actually remove the link -- I commented it to allow testing without removing my Firefox lockfile)

A different approach, but given your problem description, this should eliminate listing profiles with not associate `lock` symlink present. Let me know if you have questions.

Comment: The [BashPitfalls #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#hosts.3D.28_.24.28aws_....29_.29) violation is the only thing that catches my eye as a place where things might be tightened up (and of course, that's only a really big concern if there are unusual filenames on hand; I've seen Cygwin systems where $HOME contained spaces, but it's not a very usual case). I suppose one way to fix it would be to make the logic something more like `readarray -d '' lockfiles < <(find "$moz" -type l -name lock -printf '%P\0')` (`%P` itself strips content before `"$moz"`).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy thank you. That avoids the call to `sed` completely. Only hiccup is the `-d` option to `readarray` seems to be a bash 5 addition as bash 4.3 doesn't provide it. But even without it, that is a cleaner solution.

Comment: Hmm. Without `-d`, I don't think `readarray` handles NULs correctly; if I spin up bash 4.3, `readarray foo < <(printf '%s\0' one two three)` discards `two` and `three`. Thus, it might be necessary to switch from `\0` to `\n` (and use the `-t` argument) to make older `readarray`s work properly; or, of course, one can use `while IFS= read -r -d '' lockfile; do lockfiles+=( "$lockfile" ); done < <(...)` to have compatibility that goes back to the bash 3.x series.

Comment: I looked past that and with only one lock file -- glad you caught it.

Comment: Thanks for the help here.